# Attempting to use Bluetooth and both cores

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, bluetooth, raspberry-pi-pico

To use both cores I send commands to my Raspberry Pi Pico W which should do tasks asynchronously, depending on commands sent. Code to run Bluetooth is from [here](https://github.com/makeuseofcode/Raspberry-Pi-Pico-W-WH-Bluetooth-Example-in-MicroPython). I run a sequence of LED's on a separate thread:

```
# Import necessary modules
from machine import Pin, ADC
import uasyncio as a
import bluetooth
import time as t
import sys
from ble_simple_peripheral import BLESimplePeripheral
import _thread

# Create a Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) object
ble = bluetooth.BLE()

# Create an instance of the BLESimplePeripheral class with the BLE object
sp = BLESimplePeripheral(ble)

# Create a Pin object for the onboard LED, configure it as an output
led = Pin("LED", Pin.OUT)
re = Pin(15, Pin.OUT)
gr = Pin(6, Pin.OUT)
bl = Pin(1, Pin.OUT)
temp_sensor = ADC(4)
conversion_factor = 3.3 / 65535
event = False

# Initialize the LED state to 0 (off)
led_state = 0

# Define a callback function to handle received data
def on_rx(data):
    print("Data received: ", data)  # Print the received data
    global led_state  # Access the global variable led_state   
    global event
    if data == b'toggle\r\n':  
        led.value(not led_state)  # Toggle the LED state (on/off)
        led_state = 1 - led_state  # Update the LED state
    if data == b'leds\r\n': 
        event = True              # Update global event to true
    if data == b'ledsoff\r\n':
        event = False              # Update global event to false
    if data == b'temp\r\n':        # if temp request is recieved determine onboard temp
        reading = temp_sensor.read_u16() * conversion_factor
        temperature = 27 - (reading - 0.706)/0.001721
        temperature_data = str(temperature).encode()
        print('data sent: ',  temperature_data)
        sp.send(temperature_data)

async def green(): #green led async code
    gr.value(1)
    await a.sleep(2)
    gr.value(0)
    await a.sleep(2)

async def blue(): #blue led async code
    for i in range(4):
        bl.value(1)
        await a.sleep(0.5)
        bl.value(0)
        await a.sleep(0.5)

async def red(): #red led async code
    for i in range(10):
        re.value(1)
        await a.sleep(0.2)
        re.value(0)
        await a.sleep(0.2)

async def ma(): #use async to run connected LED's
    
    taskg = a.create_task(green())
    taskb = a.create_task(blue())
    taskr = a.create_task(red())

    await taskg
    await taskr
    await taskb

def numba2_thread(): # Run LED's using async on separate thread 
    global event
    while True:
        if event == 'run':
            a.run(ma())
        else:
            _thread.exit()


# Start main infinite loop
while True:
    if sp.is_connected():  # Check if a BLE connection is established
        sp.on_write(on_rx)  # Set the callback function for data reception
    if event == True: #if event is changed to true start new thread
        event = 'run' 
        _thread.start_new_thread(numba2_thread, ())
```

Runs perfectly until I try to turn on the LED by sending `b'leds\r\n'` using "Serial Bluetooth Terminal" from Play store. Once the led sequence started its loop I can only send one more request after which it doesn't respond to further commands.